# Generate document ID server side

Tags: couchdb

When creating a document and letting Couch create the ID for you, does it check if the ID already exists, or could I still produce a conflict?

I need to generate UUIDs in my app, and wondered if it would be any different than letting Couch do it.

Comment: there some reason you cant make your own document ids?

Comment: How are people reading this question? I AM generating ids myself, I just wondered if there is anything to consider compared to letting couch do it.

Comment: well as kxepal mentions in his answer, the feature exists for clients that *cannot* create their own document ids, and is not a reccomended use pattern.  *why* do you want the server to set the id?

Comment: So I can modify documents locally really quick and batch document creates/updates using `_bulk_docs`.

Comment: You can and should give a document id, even when using the bulk document interface.  Skipping that step makes the problem of resubmitted requests creating duplicate documents *even worse*.  On the other hand, if you *do* assign ID's, and part of the request reaches couchdb twice (as in the case of a reconnecting proxy), then your response will include some conflicts, which you can safely ignore, you know the conflict was from *you*, in the same request.

Comment: @dequestarmappartialsetattr if that was an answer I'd accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can and should give a document id, even when using the [bulk document interface](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API). Skipping that step makes the problem of resubmitted requests creating duplicate documents even worse. On the other hand, if you do assign ID's, and part of the request reaches couchdb twice (as in the case of a reconnecting proxy), then your response will include some conflicts, which you can safely ignore, you know the conflict was from you, in the same request

Answer (score 2):

Use [POST /db](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/common.html#post--db) request for that, but you should be aware the fact that the underlying HTTP POST method is not idempotent, and a client may automatic retry it due to a problem some networking problems, which may create multiple documents in the database.

Answer (score 1):

As Kxepal already mentioned it is generally not recommended to POST a document without providing your own _id.

You could, however, use [`GET /_uuids`](https://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/server/common.html#uuids) to retrieve a list of UUIDs from the server and use that for storing your documents. The UUIDs returned will depend on the [algorithm](https://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/misc.html#uuids/algorithm) that is used, but the chance of a duplicate are (for most purposes) insignificantly small.

Comment: " it is generally not recommended to POST a document without providing your own _id." - `POST` when you have the Id? You mean that should be a `PUT` right? `POST` is when the server generates the ID and `PUT` when you provide one your self. http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#POST and http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/put-vs-post/

Comment: @Daniel actually, you may `POST` with explicit document id: just add `_id` field to request JSON payload. The effect would be the same as for PUT, but due to same reasons why `POST` isn't recommended you may sometimes receive errors about conflict update instead of success report.

Comment: Yes I know you can, but should you if you conform to how you generally look at the use of POST and PUT?

Comment: @daniel: some older http clients are not able to use methods other than GET, HEAD, and POST.  as such couchdb allows all data modifying requests to be encoded as POST.

Comment: again, I know you can, but I you have the choice, wouldn't it be more appropriate to use PUT if you provide the ID? Refering to the statment in the answer above: "...it is generally not recommended to POST a document without providing your own _id." <em>WITHOUT</em>